# What to use for writing blog in my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogs, openwysiwyg

I want to develop my blog website in ASP.NET. What could be the best way I can write my blog through?

I mean will Tiny MCE work for me, last time when I used it I faced terrible formatting issues. Because my blog will include code, different formatting, pictures etc. Please suggest me how to post blog?

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 and SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3):

Why write your own from scratch? Take a look at Orchard CMS.  It's an opensource .NET CMS being developed with help from Microsoft  http://www.orchardproject.net/

Its fairly new, so there's still some features missing, but its really easy to get setup and since you're a .NET developer you can add your own functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jamiegs.  Blogging is by and large a solved problem.  Why not use an existing package?  Most packages will include much more than anything you'd put together in your spare time not to mention that you'll benefit from all of the field testing too.

I settled on hosted [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.com) and just pointed my domain there.  Hosted Wordpress is somewhat more limited than [self-hosted](http://www.wordpress.org) (you can't install your own themes, etc...) but I've hardly found it restrictive.  Their documentation around the various shortcodes for displaying source code or embedding maps is pretty complete.

Comment: if you're going the hosted route, I'd recommend Squarespace.com over Wordpress, but if you want to code in some of your own features you wouldn't be able to go with a hosted solution.

Comment: If you want to include custom modules, sure, you'll need something self-hosted that you can control but if you just want a place to post code examples there's no reason for it.  I'd never looked at squarespace.com before but just from the home page I see one major advantage of wordpress.com - it's free until you want some addons.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Obout's html editor almost a year now without any problems. http://obout.com/editor_new/sample_full.aspx . Ajax Toolkit has free lite version of Obout's editor.

Comment: @Chris If you are a student you can get obout suite for free.If not you can use Ajax toolkit which has the same html editor.